# Image replacement problem with JS and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a simple JS function changing the background image of my website for each "page" - there are actually no separate pages, just JS changing the content area and background.  Here is the code I have:

```js
var selector = 'home';

function changeBG() {
    if ( selector == 'portfolio' ) {
        document.bg_img.src = 'imgs/sandwiches/BLT_smlbw.jpg';
    }
    else if ( selector == 'contact' ) {
        document.bg_img.src = 'imgs/sandwiches/eggSammerSml.jpg';
    }
    else {
        document.bg_img.src = 'imgs/plums4.jpg';
    }
}
```

and the HTML

```html
<!-- bg -->
<img class="bg" id="bg_img" src="" alt="background_image" name="background_image" />
<!-- /bg -->

<!-- content -->
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- left nav -->
<div id="left" class="content">
    <img src="imgs/sandwich_logo.png" width="384" height="73"     alt="sandwich_enthusiast" name="sandwich_enthusiast" />
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#about" id="about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="portfolio" onclick="selector = 'portfolio'; changeBG();">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" id="contact" onclick="selector = 'contact'; changeBG();">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://glosee.ca/blog" id="blog">the sammers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /left nav -->
```

In Chrome, Safari, and IE8 the image loads perfectly fine, but in FF the image loads as a background image in the wrapper div on the first click, then into the overall background on a second click.

Any ideas of how this can be fixed?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but using the global selector variable is insane.  Give your changeBG function a parameter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your advice/answers.  I ended up going with JQuery to get it together.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to help avoid cross-browser issues.

If you want to go ahead without one however, you could try using standard DOM manipulation methods:

```
document.getElementById('bg_img').setAttribute('src', 'imgs/sandwiches/BLT_smlbw.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is fine. This might have something to do with **`bg`** class assigned to **`bg_img`** image. Probably, the **`bg`** has some unsupportable attribute which not work with FF.

**EDIT:**

To change the background of your page, why don't you just replace the `document.bg_img.src` with `document.body.background`.

Comment: Any idea what that could be? The css is minimal: .bg {
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:5000;
}

Comment: Do you want to change the background of your webpage against each link selection?

Comment: I see where you're going with that, but I specifically have it set up this way so the BG image resizes with the browser window.  This was the only way I knew how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
function changeBG()
{
    var img = docuemnt.getElementById ("bg_img");
    if( selector == 'portfolio' )
    {
            img.src = 'imgs/sandwiches/BLT_smlbw.jpg';
    }

    else if( selector == 'contact' )
    {
            img.src = 'imgs/sandwiches/eggSammerSml.jpg';
    }
    else
    {
            img.src = 'imgs/plums4.jpg';
    }


}
```